# When to expect IEnumerable and when to expect IQueryable from a Linq query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I am having some trouble understanding when Linq is giving me an IQueryable result and when it is giving me an IEnumerable result.

Example:
I am using EF and I have two entities `Location` and `Configuration`.
Each `Location` can have multiple `Configurations`.

The following query is giving me an IQueryable as result:

```
Context.Locations.Where(l => l.Name == "SomeName")
```

whereas the following is giving me an IEnumerable as result:

```
Context.Locations.Where(l => l.Name == "SomeName").First().Configurations.Select(c => c)
```

Why is that?

Comment: The first query is giving you `IQueryable`? Are you positive? That should materialize a single object, there should be no `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram You are right. I removed the .First() from my example to clarify.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, LINQ extension methods on IQueryable (defined in [Queryable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.queryable.aspx)) return IQueryables, and the ones on IEnumerable (defined in [Enumerable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx)) return IEnumerables.  In this particular case, Configurations is a collection (IEnumerable) on the first returned Location object.  Therefore the `.Select` call returns an IEnumerable.

EDIT: To make it all execute remotely, you could try this:

```
Context.Locations.Where(l => l.Name == "SomeName").Configurations
```

Assuming that your filter on Locations is only going to return one row, you should get the same result.  Of course it will be an IQueryable, but that shouldn't make a difference.  If you need to materialize it, you can do something like:

```
Context.Locations.Where(l => l.Name == "SomeName").Configurations.ToList()
```

Comment: That makes kinda sense as Configurations is a collection in the EF. But in the database it is still a separate table. How can I make sure that the entire query will be executed in SQL Server and not in memory?

Comment: Try moving the First call further down the stack.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I will accept this answer because you answered my question. Regarding you suggestions for executing it on the server, it does not work. The result from from `Context.Locations.Where(..)` does not contain a definition for Configurations since it is of type `IQueriable<Location>`. I am a little bit concerned about some of my other queries now which are much larger than this. I guess I will have to use SQL Profiler to verify what is actually executed on the server.

Comment: For those who are curious: my query, `Context.Locations.Where(l => l.Name == "SomeName").First().Configurations.Select(c => c)`actually executed in two steps on the SQL Server. First getting the Location, and then using `sp_executesql`to get Configurations. By re-writing the Linq query I could get everything executed in SQL Server in one go, which is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, IQueryable allows for remote data sources (like SQL Server). It will work against the database, if possible. IEnumerable works with in-memory collections.

So, if you are querying a SQL Server database, you will get an IQueryable. Otherwise it'll be an IEnumerable.

This [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/erickt/archive/2006/10/23/iqueryable-t-vs-ienumerable-t.aspx) may further help you.